# Android RelativeLayout marginBottom not working

Tags: android

I am trying to set marginBottom for RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:marginBottom="15dp"
    android:marginLeft="10dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <!-- Rest of thelayout -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

But, the marginBottom has no effect. Why?

Comment: Please add more description of your question.

Comment: @Mohom.R I guess question is clear. What don't you understand?

Comment: `layout_marginBottom`, `layout_marginTop`. If this is a typo correct it because it invites unhelpful answers.

Comment: In the case of margins **parent view** is important, so you should share _wrapper_ of your `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know why but marginBottom does not work if you set its height to wrap_content.You can do the following things:

> 1) Set its height to match_parent.
>
> 2) Use paddingBottom instead of marginBottom.
>
> 3) Use a LinearLayout instead.

Comment: @overflowed Margin is handled by parent layout. As everything prefixed by `layout_`. If parent does not support margin, you won't get margin on child views.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your attribute as below

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
```

Comment: It is not android:marginBottom, instead android:layout_marginBottom

Answer (score 0):

If child views doesn't fill the screen, you can not observe the bottom margin.

That's why, height must be **"match_parent"**.

If the parent view of the RelativeLayout is ScrollView, height of the RelativeLayout should be **"wrap_content"** and add this line to ScrollView in xml.

`android:fillViewport="true"`

Also,

```
android:marginBottom="15dp"
android:marginLeft="10dp"
```

wrong. Try this,

```
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```